# Run keyword And Continue On Failure - get check status

Tags: robotframework

I need to get the status of a check (PASS/FAIL) without changing the overall status of a test

```
Test 1
  ${passed}  Run keyword And Continue On Failure    Should Be Equal  1  2
  Log  ${passed}
  ${passed}  Run keyword And Continue On Failure    Should Be Equal  1  1
  Log  ${passed}
```

${passed} is always `None`. What is the right way?

---

This is at the moment my working solution :(

```
  ${passed}  ${value}    Run keyword And Ignore Error    Should Be Equal    1  2
  Run Keyword If  "${passed}"=="FAIL"  Run keyword And Continue On Failure  FAIL
```

Rr

Comment: Although there are several ways for getting the current status of the test,  I'm not sure if that is your goal. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I need to execute a keyword and if it fails the test must be marked as failed. Morevover if the keyword as failed I need to save that status on a variable

Comment: You say that you need "to execute a keyword and **if it fails the test must be marked as failed**". But in the question you say that the status of the test should not be changed. What is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [Run keyword And Continue On Failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure) does not return any value. It was never meant to.

For this purpose use [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status)

> This keyword returns Boolean True if the keyword that is executed
>   succeeds and False if it fails.

```
${passed} =   Run Keyword And Return Status   Should be Equal   1   2
Run Keyword Unless   ${passed}   Log   The previous step FAILED!
```

But even with just the *Run keyword And Continue On Failure* should have the failure of the encapsulated keyword in the log.